# Getting SmartCard certificate into Windows service local store (mmc)

Tags: certificate, smartcard

I need the certificate from my smart card to be in the Windows service local sotre. I opened the store with mmc -> snap-in -> certificates.
I used different little tools to see informations(ATR etc.) about my smartcard and they all worked out.

I can see a lot of certificates there, but the one from my smartcard is missing in the store. The folder 'Smartcard trusted Roots' is empty. Windows gets the .cer/.pfx-data from smart cards automatically, right?
Or is there no chance, i can do it without using low-level programming(APDU-commands etc.)

Answer (score 1):

First read this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404288(v=WS.10).aspx

As it's written

> 1. A logged-on user inserts a smart card.
> 2. CertPropSvc is notified that a smart card was inserted.
> 3. CertPropSvc reads all certificates from all inserted smart cards. The certificates are written to the user's personal certificate store

So yes, gnerally certificates should pop up in User Personal Certificate Store automatically.

First thing to check is that you have CertPropSvc service runnig.
Another thing that I saw that some smart cards drivers doesn't work with Windows API. One example I know was old RSA tokens. We have changed them to [Gemalto .NET cards](http://support.gemalto.com/index.php?id=idprime_dot_net) and [USB readers](http://www.gemalto.com/products/usb_shell_token_v2/index.html) because of this

Note: In the artcle I linked it's written that this is valid for Windows 7 and 2008 but it worked for me on XP and Vista.

Comment: The technet article was exactly what I was looking for, but the OP is "how to load the certificate to the local machine Personal store." That article (number 3 in your bullets) confirms the default behaviour is to load the certificate to the current user Personal store.